# Old Facebook account is hacked

Tags: facebook

Old Facebook account is hacked again. I have a new Facebook that I had to start months ago  I got email my one that I use daily is ok but because of something on the hacked one my is disabled I have appealed but haven't heard

Comment: It used to tell you why it was disabled